# Warning: This line has a length of 82. Maximum allowed is 80

Tags: javascript

VSCode is showing this warning:
**Warning: This line has a length of 82. Maximum allowed is 80**

The affected line is this:

```
function getThatNewPath (myParam, myFirstParam, mySecondParam, anotherParam) {
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you asking how to insert new-lines between the parameters? Put the cursor next to the comma, hit Delete, and hit Enter, repeat on every comma, finally add a new-line just before the closing parenthese. VSCode will take care of the correct indentation.

Comment: In your command line `eslint --fix`? Assuming you're using eslint.

Comment: `"prettier.printwidth": 180` in User Settings JSON in VSCode, if you have installed the amazing Prettier extension. Or you could rather https://editorconfig.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since it is a warning, you don't really need to fix it, but if you want anyway, I'd suggest making the line shorter, either by shortening your param names or by using multiple lines to achieve the same result.

Of course, if you split the line into multiple lines this depends on the coding guidelines you apply.

E.g.:

```
function getVideoAlbumResource (myParam, myFirstParam, mySecondParam,
                                anotherParam, ..., finalParam) {
```

Since you're using JavaScript you could also pass an object containing your params, which you could destructure later on inside the function.

E.g.:

```
function getVideoAlbumResource (params) {
    const { myParam, myFirstParam, mySecondParam, anotherParam } = params;
```

Or you could also destructure your passed object right away in the function header and make it so that you use a fresh line for each property you deconstruct

E.g.:

```js
function getVideoAlbumResource ({
    myParam,
    myFirstParam,
    mySecondParam,
    anotherParam,
}) {
    // your code here
```

Of course you could refer to your params by using the dot notation (`params.myParam`, etc.) too.

Answer (score 2):

You can do one of those 3 things :

- Reformat your line into multiple line to not exceed 80
- or change your eslint config of max-len to put more than 80
- or add an es-lint ignore on top of your line to ignore this rule for this particular line

Answer (score 1):

I like listing each parameter on their own line when there are 4 or more of them:

```
function getVideoalbumResource (
  myParam,
  myFirstParam,
  mySecondParam,
  anotherParam
) {
  // code
}
```

Comment: It's silly to have 80 chars per line in the first place. It's 2020. https://prettier.io/docs/en/rationale.html#print-width

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I'd find a mail long argument list even more silly ...

Comment: @Teemu true that

Answer (score 1):

I think it is your tslint.json which is causing the warning.
In tslint.json, change the value of `max-line-length` to your desired value.
eg-

```
"max-line-length": [
      true,
      140
    ],
```

Comment: There's no tslint.json

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your rules:

```
"max-len": ["error", { code: 140 }]
```